# AWS S3. Correctly restrict access rights of images in bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a REST api, and a Ionic 2 mobile apps (for android and IOS). The mobile user takes a photo from the mobile phone, and the sends the photo to the server which successfully saves the photo in the bucket.

Now I have to get the image from the AWS S3 bucket. I would need to access the images by their **URL**, and in the same time I want to restrict non-app users to see the photos.

What would be a good aproach for solving this task? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to access the images from their URL? What would be accessing them?

Comment: I have a chat and I have to append the images to messages. As Ionic is Angular based, I want to load the image by the url. In the same time I need this image to be unavailable for direct access from browser

Comment: HI @KateCebotari , I am going through the similar situation. Did you get solution to the above question.

Comment: unfortunately no. I have made the bucket public just for prototype version but still have to find a correct solution for this ))